# Do I need to reset model weights in Kfold loop?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I want to check the accuracy of my model with Kfold. I want the model weights to be reset between each iteration, so I don't continue to calculate on the previous iterations weights. Is the code below enough? Or do the model exist outside the loop in keras backend?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D)
    #Add more layers
    model.compile()
    model.fit()

    #Calculate accuracy for each test element (pseudo code)
    modelprediction=model.predict(testvalue1,2,3,4,5)
    indexes = tf.argmax(modelprediction, axis=1)

    print(totalAccuracy)
```

Do the sess = tf.Interactive and Keras backend save the weights somehow? Should i reset both sess and keras? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `model = Sequential()` (i.e. you define the model) *inside* the loop, your model is indeed "reset" (newly defined, actually) in each iteration, so you don't need to take any further actions.